# Find the region bounded by $y=x \sin x$, and $y=x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Find the area bounded by the region $y=x \sin(x)$, and $y=x$, for $0\le x\le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

### My attempt

Area $=\int_\limits{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(x-x\sin(x))dx$

After integrating I got:

$$[\frac{x^2}{2}+x\cos(x)-\sin(x)]_0^\frac{\pi}{2}$$

## Is my answer right?

Which leads me to get approximately .2337 units squared.

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: @PeterForeman Because I'm new at doing this.

Comment: You don't need to say "units squared". Otherwise it's right

Comment: That’s correct, though I might show the exact answer $\pi^2/8  - 1$ before the approximation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct to four decimal places (see e.g. [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+x+and+x+sin%28x%29+for+0+<+x+<+pi%2F2) for confirmation), just make sure you can also get the correct exact answer (in terms of $\pi$).

Comment: Is there a way to do that for volume?

Comment: Do you mean find the volume between two 3-dimensional curves? By the way, you can also rotate a 2-dimensional area around a line, or you can make squares/semicircles/triangles which have the 'height' of the curve as their base.

Comment: @TobyMak No on WolframAlpha to do volume

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get what you mean. Can you explain further?

Comment: @TobyMak https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volume+of+a+x%5E2+from+0+%3C+x+%3C+2 to do this I found it thanks by the way.

Comment: The (changing) radius is $x^2$, so at a particular $x$, the area of the disk is $\pi(x^2)^2 = \pi x^4$. Now, the volume can be represented as the sum of all the areas of the disks from $x=0$ to $2$, which is where the definite integral comes in.